# What could we produce with a space based industry?

Tags: asteroid, mining, reduced-gravity-manufacturing

The astroid belt is great place to start humanity’s journey through space.  I want to know, what materials and items could be produced from asteroids.  I’m mainly going to ask for useful items, such as NEMS, propellant(xenon, hydrogen), spacecraft parts, construction materials, and drilling tools.  I want to know as well, where to find these resources.

Comment: Don’t we have to get to the asteroid belt first?

Comment: I did a quick search to see if any elements in particular have been ruled out as definitely not present in asteroids.  I landed on some really out-there speculation (based on a possibly erroneous measurement of 33 Polyhymnia's density) that [asteroids might harbor elements we haven't observed yet in the "island of stability"](https://www.sciencealert.com/asteroids-may-be-hiding-never-seen-elements-from-beyond-the-periodic-table).  My guess is nothing is actually ruled out, but it's a hard answer to properly support.

Comment: @JonCuster It's a kind of "hen-and-egg" problem. If there's nothing useful in the belt, why bother finding/funding a way to reach it? If the belt can't be reached, doesn't everything in it automatically become useless? So "how" and "why" are equally valid (or equally invalid, if you're a pessimist) questions.